# How to find pairs of primes satisfying certain properties?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues

This question is related to [a question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/q/245719/54628) on MathOverflow.

> Can you find an infinite sequence of pairs $p,q$ of primes satisfying the following conditions?

- $p$ and $q$ are distinct with $p<q$

  $p\geq 73$

  both $p$ and $q$ are congruent to $1$ modulo $4$

  $q$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$

  (optional) $p$ should be as small as possible (for example $p=73$ would be great)

The first example would be $p=73$ and $q=89$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, even with $p = 73$. The conditions that $q$ be a quadratic residue mod $p$ and congruent to $1$ mod $4$ are congruence conditions; by the Chinese remainder theorem, you can express them as one congruence. Now Dirichlet's theorem tells you there are infinitely many primes in the arithmetic progression determined by this congruence.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Assuming we fix $p=73$, is there any known information on the distribution of the sequence of values for $q$ given by this method?